# Pure CSS - Style a select box when a selection has been made

Tags: css

After searching for the past two hours I have to throw in the towel and ask the question myself.

How do I style a select box using only CSS (not Javascript) so that if a selection has not been made, the opacity is set to .5, but once a selection is made the select box is opacity 1?

I see a lot of questions and answers about changing specific option colors, etc, but I want to affect the entire select box itself. It seems very simple:

Nothing selected yet? opacity: .5;

Anything is selected from the dropdown? opacity: 1;

I can't seem to find the trigger to know whether something is selected, and yes, I've tried using :checked on the select box and on the option.

Any help would be wonderful, but I'm thinking this is a limitation of CSS itself and can't be done without Javascript intervention. Thanks guys!

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd need JS for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible by setting `required` attribute to your select. It works by checking the correct value of that select. If you select an option with an empty value it will be marked as invalid. You can make that option hidden and use as a placeholder. It will disappear once user makes a selection.

```css
select:invalid
{
  opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

```html
<select required>
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Please select an option</option>
  <option>123</option>
  <option>123</option>
  <option>123</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That is exactly the angle I needed. The only catch I could foresee is if you really didn't want the select options to be required to submit the form. But for my purposes, this was perfect and I got it to work exactly as I wanted it to. Thank you very much!